# how to write C code to arrange the input data in matrix form?

Tags: c

Ex: input = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,. . . . . . .(n-2),(n-1),n}

i want out as follows

Where number of columns and row are defined

For this example columns = 6
                 rows = input/columns;

```
         _                       _
        | 0, 1,  2,   3,   4,   5 |
        | 6, 7,  8,   9,   .    . |
matrix =| .  .   .    .    .    . |
        | .  .   .    .    .    . |
        | .  .   .  (n-2),(n-1),n | 
        |_                       _|
```

Please any body help me..

Comment: Please read the FAQ.  tl;dr - do something, post code

Comment: If `input` is an array of numbers retrieved from the user, then you should first sort it using a [sorting algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) because you can't always trust the user to input numbers in the right order. Once you know the numbers are in order, create `matrix` with the appropriate dimensions, and then loop through `input` and place the values in their correct places in `matrix`.

Comment: This reminds my of my current programming homework which is based on this issue

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anyone can *answer* this question as is, because it's not well defined... but I can probably help point you in the right direction.

A matrix is just a 2 dimensional array, so look up how to do that in C, something like:

```
int matrix[2][3]; // a static, uninitialized, 2 by 3 matrix

int fill = 0;
for(int row = 0; row < 2; row++)
    for(int col = 0; col < 3; col++, fill++)
        matrix[row][col] = fill; //will initialize the array to 0, 1, 2,
                                 //                             3, 4, 5
```

They come in either statically allocated (as above) or dynamically allocated (use `malloc()`). If you're coming up with dimensions on the fly, you'll need to use a dynamically allocated matrix.

I'd guess based on your comment: `Where number of columns and row are defined...rows = input/columns` that means the number of rows is based on the `input` which comes from the user (`stdin`) so you'll have to do this dynamically.